# Positioning an individual label on a scatter plot in AMcharts

Tags: amcharts

good day

I hope someone can help me. I created a scatter plot on AMcharts and each data point has its own label, but as soon as I put in more data the labels over flow. I have tried positioning each label individually, but I cant seem to get it right. I also tried using a labelFunction to change the position of an individual data point, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Can someone please help me.

I'm really struggling with this thing.

javaScript

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "xy",
"pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
"theme": "none",
"dataProvider": [{
    "y": 10,
    "x": 14,
    "value": 59,
    "y2": -5,
    "x2": -3,
    "value2": 44
}, {
    "y": 5,
    "x": 3,
    "value": 50,
    "y2": -15,
    "x2": -8,
    "value2": 12
}, {
    "y": -10,
    "x": 8,
    "value": 19,
    "y2": -4,
    "x2": 6,
    "value2": 35
}, {
    "y": -6,
    "x": 5,
    "value": 65,
    "y2": -5,
    "x2": -6,
    "value2": 168
}, {
    "y": 15,
    "x": -4,
    "value": 92,
    "y2": -10,
    "x2": -8,
    "value2": 102
}, {
    "y": 13,
    "x": 1,
    "value": 8,
    "y2": -2,
    "x2": 0,
    "value2": 41
}, {
    "y": 1,
    "x": 6,
    "value": 35,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2": -3,
    "value2": 16
}],
"valueAxes": [{
    "position":"bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0
}, {
    "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left"
}],
"graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "x:<b>[[x]]</b> y:<b>[[y]]</b><br>value:<b>[[value]]     </b>",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "valueField": "value",
    "xField": "x",
    "yField": "y",
    "maxBulletSize": 100,
    "labelText": "[[x]]",
    "labelFunction": function(obj,label) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(obj.bulletGraphics.node.nextElementSibling);
        },100); // delay to generate the element
        return label;
    }
}, {
    "balloonText": "x:<b>[[x]]</b> y:<b>[[y]]</b><br>value:<b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "valueField": "value2",
    "xField": "x2",
    "yField": "y2",
    "maxBulletSize": 100
}],
"marginLeft": 46,
"marginBottom": 35
```

});

Comment: Could you show us your code? Make a fiddle? I don't have the time to rework your case from the scrath.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mier007/7gt3bad0/1/ this is what I have. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. PLEASE say you can help me

Comment: For some reasons i have trouble with the amcharts sources loading in JSFiddle... Is this only for me? It's new for me, yesterday i had no problems.

Comment: Well I was working on the file til about an hour ago and it happened to me as well. I did not update the file, but when i tried to open it up again it also did not want to display. I'm gonna copy it over in a different fiddle and try again. Just give me five minutes

Comment: Ok, so you want two data points at exact the same position?

Comment: I got it working. You have to copy the sources directly into the fiddle. For some reasons the https is blocking the external sources.

Comment: Well if it happens like that yes, my main problem is getting the labels not to overlap because as soon as I put in more data, the labels overlap and you can't see anything. My boss doesn't seem to care that it's easier said than done.

Comment: I guess there's no solution?

Comment: Phew... you're lucky that i have nothing to do right now and can focus on your problem. :) But i got something working i think. So maybe there's an answer in another 10 minutes or so..

Comment: Boooooya!!!!!!!!!!! :D

Comment: Ok 10 minutes would have been nice, but it gets bit more complicated i need more debugging. But it seems like i could get it working.

Comment: Take your time. I've been stuggling for a week

Comment: Btw the same datapoints HAVE to be in the same graph? Otherwise it would be easier i think.

Comment: It needs to be ONE GRAPH with about 40 data points. All in one graph. I also don't see the logic behind it, i know, but ja.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mier007/y0fjwc3z/ if you look at that Fiddle you will see the basic idea he wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what i got for you is this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72on0wne/3/).
It uses the `labelFunction` to move the label. As `labelFunction` returns a blank string you have to do this with `\u00a0` (space) or `\n` (new line).
So the function checks, if the previous(!) point has the same(!) coordinates.
You could modify it to check the whole dataset and see if any datapoint is near.
I hope you can work with this. :)

Comment: Oh and sry for the break. I had to focus on sth else in the meantime.

Comment: Hi Gerric. can you please help me again. what do I modify to check if the labels are near eachother

Comment: Ehm... i guess you should write a function, which iterates through your data and looks for x/y values nearer than a given parameter.